# Why should native functions be used instead of system calls?

Tags: ruby

The code reviewer requested changes in a piece of code similar to this:

```
system("grep foo /tmp/bar")
```

or this:

```
res, err, st = Open3.capture3("grep foo /tmp/bar")
```

The reviewer said:

> Just read the file natively in Ruby, no need to fork a sub-command.

Why does the reviewer believe it is better to use Ruby's native functions like for example `File.read` even though there is no untrusted data on the sub-command call?

Comment: Counter question: why do you believe running a sub-command is better than calling Ruby's built-in method? What was your motivation here? (assuming it was your code)

Comment: To clarify: I didn't write that code, I'm actually the reviewer gathering good arguments.
The person who wrote that probably doesn't have any familiarity with the language.

Comment: _"Why does the reviewer believe [...]"_ is a slightly odd way to put the question if the reviewer is in fact you ;-)

Comment: You are probably right. I was unsure how to write a question about best practices, so that's what I came up with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best thing would obviously be to ask the reviewer, not us. But I can speculate.

- Calling out to a subshell is less efficient, plain and simple. It requires an additional process, whereas `File.read` runs in the current process.
- Your code is now OS-dependent. Windows, for instance, does not have a `grep` command, but `File.read` will work on any OS that runs Ruby.
- At a glance, a subshell makes me think something funny is going on. If I see `File.read`, I expect that in Ruby code. If I see a `system` call, I begin to suspect something strange is going on, causing me to doubt the nature of the code.

For what it's worth, grepping in Ruby is still very simple. In fact, it's literally called [`grep`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep).

```
File.readlines("/tmp/bar").grep(/foo/)
```

If I encountered the `grep` code in the question in a code review, I likely would have flagged it for the reasons above.